# JavaScript Split Total into 10 separate fields in Adobe PDF

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe

I am working on a fillable PDF. I have various calculated fields that all sum into one called Total. I then need to split total up into 10 individual boxes (8 before decimal, 2 after) with one number in each field when applicable.

So for example if the Total (which can vary in amount) is 201.50 
I need nothing to show up in Amt1, Amt2, Amt3, Amt4, Amt5, 
2 to show up in Amt6, 
0 to show up in Amt7, 
1 to show up in Amt8, 
5 to show up in Amt9, 
 
0 to show up in Amt10

So for Amt10 under Run custom validation script for the last decimal place I put : getField("Total").value = event.value.slice(-1); which did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those böxlis can be a real pain in the butt, and should be avoided.

Instead use the comb property of the field, and use the other properties (right align and number format) to properly display the values.

With this, your fields will retain useable values, and display properly.

Answer (score 0):

If "Total" is calculated, getField("Total").value is returning a number. Use getField("Total").valueAsString if you need to use String methods.